# Java do while validation

Tags: java, validation, do-while

I don't understand why only my while statement is working and it does not move on to the for statement for the valid integer.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Factorial {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long posNumber;
        long x;
        long fact = 1;

        do {
            System.out.print("Enter a number between 2 and 15: ");
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            posNumber = in.nextLong();
        } while (posNumber >= 2 || posNumber <= 15);


        for (x = 1; x <= posNumber; x++)
            fact = fact*x;
            System.out.println("Factorial of " +posNumber+ " is " +fact);

        }

    }
```

Comment: It's in your for loop's condition. It should be `posNumber < 2 || posNumber > 15`.

Comment: Every number is either greater than 2 or less than 15 (and some numbers are both).  So what you wrote is equivalent to `while (true)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try something like, if you plan to get numbers in a loop:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
do {
    System.out.print("Enter a number between 2 and 15: ");
    posNumber = in.nextLong();

    for (x = 1; x <= posNumber; x++)
      fact = fact*x;
      System.out.println("Factorial of " +posNumber+ " is " +fact);
    }
} while (posNumber >= 2 || posNumber <= 15);
```

Or you can change the condition (in case to run it just once):

```
while (posNumber < 2 || posNumber > 15);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want your program to continue asking the user if the number is invalid. That means if it is less than 2 or greater than 15. Replace your while condition with:

```
do {
    ...
} while (posNumber < 2 || posNumber > 15);
```

If the user enters a 1, `posNumber < 2` will evaluate to `true` causing the loop to repeat and ask for a new number.

If the user enters 3, both `posNumber < 2` and `posNumber > 15` will evaluate to `false` and the loop will break and then your for loop will execute.